# Python3 - closest previous and next element in a list (treated as cyclic) with a valid value

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list of values... some are valid, some not, the invalid contain None. I test each element for validity. When I find an invalid element, I need to find indexes of the closest previous and the closest next valid value. I need to treat the list as a cycle, so if there are no valid elements before/after the initial element, it should search from the end/start of the list... This way, if there is at least one valid value in the list, both the previous and the next valid value will be found (it can be the same index, if there is only one valid value in the list).

Ok, it is complicated to explain and it gets very complicated when I try to code it. But I am sure there is some simple and idiomatical way to do it. Can you help me?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Step one: Create unit tests for typical use cases. Step two: Implement the container. Step three: Add non-typical use cases, like an empty list or one with just one element.

Comment: Make an attempt to code it and when you have a specific difficulty, other than a Syntax Error, post it and ask a specific question.  @UlrichEckhardt 's advice is excellent.

Comment: I have the specific difficulty described in the question, I do not know how to specify more clearly. I do not care for empty lists or lists with one element - it is not a problem and cannot happen with the real data anyway. I do not even know what does unit test and container mean. I am just a biologist trying to process some data, not a programmer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the useless answers, I will ask elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither I am a programmer, but I use something like this for analysing data around the 24-hour clock (that means, for example 23:00 is before 01:00 etc.). Then I compute the unknown values as a weighted averages of the previous and next known values. The parameters are the position of the unknown element in the list and the list itself:

```
def get_prev_known(i, some_list):
    for j, item in enumerate(some_list[i::-1]+some_list[:i:-1]):
        if j > 0 and item is not None:
            return (i-j) % len(some_list)

def get_next_known(i, some_list):
    for j, item in enumerate(some_list[i:]+some_list[:i]):
        if j > 0 and item is not None:
            return (i+j) % len(some_list)
```

it should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, clever solution. It saves me 20 lines of code and works as expected.